# Java: is it possible to make set of methods or anything working like it?

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, set

I would like to create a loop, that reads which methods are now about to run and execute them all. I thought about making something like:

```
set.add(milk());  set.add(doSomething());  set.add(count()); 

for(Iterator i = set.begining(); i!= set.end(); ++i){
*i; //do the method on "i"
}
```

(I don't know the implementation of sets in java yet, only c++)

I need it because the methods executed will change lots of time during gameplay and i want to avoid barrels of "if's" and mess in code

Comment: Read about [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I would think that use of a collection of interfaces, such as Runnables or Callables, would better serve the original poster.

Comment: You can use Java 8 and method references like `MyClass::milk` and stuff. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html and Runnable/Callable work well for your case too, I think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java provides the interface `Runnable` with the method `run()` that allows to pass functionality as object. (Any other interface could allow this as well but `Runnable` is the standard in Java). You could do something like this:

```
final HashSet<Runnable> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        milk(); //will execute milk()
    }
});
set.add(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        doSomething(); //will execute doSomething()
    }
});
// and so on

for(Runnable r : set) {
    r.run(); //will execute each Runnable in the set
}
```

This approach creates anonymous classes implementing `Runnable` and its `run()` method. The `run()` method of each `Runnable` implementation in the set will be called and within these `run()` methods you can do whatever you want. In this case, you simply call another function.

See [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) of anonymous classes. There is a simpler notation called [lambda-expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). But in case you are just learning Java, you should definitely learn about anonymous classes first.

---

**UPDATE:** In order to remove exactly the `Runnable` for milk, you can do this:

```
final HashSet<Runnable> set = new HashSet<>();
//store the runnable in variable so that we know which runnable to remove afterwards
final Runnable milk = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        milk(); //will execute milk()
    }
};
//add the runnable as usual
set.add(milk);
//add some other runnables
set.add(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        doSomething(); //will execute doSomething()
    }
});
// and so on

for(Runnable r : set) {
    r.run(); //will execute each Runnable in the set
}
set.remove(milk); //remove the Runnable we created first
```

Comment: But how to remove e.g. milk() from this set?

Comment: @Ikciwor - You remove it from the set.

Comment: @Ikciwor Do you mean after it has executed?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock yes, and exactly milk, not anything else

Answer (score 3):

Define each of your method as a `Runnnable` then add them to the array and iterate through calling `run()` for each.

Like

```
Runnable addMilk = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() { System.out.println("adding milk");
}
}
```

A shorter notation is possible using the new Java 8 Lambda operators

```
Runnable addMilk = () -> { System.out.println("adding milk"); };
```

There's also `Callable` if you want to return a value